# How does one thoroughly clean the silicone seal from a multicooker's lid?

Tags: pressure-cooker

We've got a Redmond RMC-P350 multicooker with pressure-cooking capabilities. While we're very satisfied so far, one thing that bothers me is that the silicone (?) seal ring on the lid now has the distinct lasting smell of some of the former culinary wonders we've produced, as well as a general yellow-ish tinge, as opposed to its original pristine opaque whiteness.

The instruction manual instructs the user to clean the seal using warm water and soap (not the dishwasher!), which we've done after every use. I've also tried to soak it in baking soda for a bit, to no effect.

Is there anything else I can do to restore the seal to its original state?

Comment: Other silicone seals survive my dishwasher fine, and it removes smells, but they can actually pick up stains in there (e.g. if a lot of oily tomatoey stuff is being ashed at the same time).  Depending on your priorities it might be worth a shot.

Comment: @ChrisH I'll give it a shot next time we start the dishwasher, thanks. We usually use the slightly colder program, so I think it should be safe. Still, I'll give the vinegar solution a go first

Comment: @ChrisH silicone is certainly dishwasher-stable, and a soak in dishwasher detergent is better than putting the seal in the dishwasher (it is designed to be best at cleaning firm items). It isn't enough to remove that much of the smell though, and the discoloration stays too, at least for my seal. In fact, that's why they sell extra seals, and in different colors - when you use one for stews, another for yogurt fermentation and a third for sweets, you don't transfer the smells.

Answer (score 2):

Baking soda isn't going to do that much for you, try soaking the seal in distilled vinegar for 30-60 minutes, then rinsing it thoroughly. I wouldn't try anything harsher than that, if the vinegar doesn't work you're better off living with it.